# What are the difference in Dialog display in lwuit?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

In Lwuit Dialogs, I have seen ***.show()*** , ***.showDialog()*** , ***.showModeless()*** and ***.showPacked(String, boolean)*** . 
What are the difference between these.
And when I use a dialog, until the dialog goes the background process not running. Is there any solution for that.

Comment: Why don't you test each of these methods !!!!

Comment: You've asked two distinct questions here, without providing context to either.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Actually it is somewhat related, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [Dialog javadoc](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Dialog.html#show%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Here clearly described what they are and where it will be use.

Comment: I think he means that the dialog blocks execution. Modal dialogs block execution which means the line after show/showModal etc. will not run until the dialog is dismissed. He might be interested to try modless dialogs based on his use cases.